# How to send password with confirmation email (PHP)

Tags: php, email, authentication, passwords

First off, I realize this is an **extremely bad practice**- however, I've seen sites that do this, and I was wondering.

Is there anyway to send a password along with registration details, and still have the password stored as a hash?

So, basically, upon registration, the user receives a confirmation email, along with their username and password, to save for reference. When a website does this, do they store the password as a hash, or as plaintext?

The password is stored as plaintext in the email- however, is it simply stored as plaintext in the server, or hashed after the email is sent?

This may seem like an odd question, but since I've seen many sites doing this, I 'd like to know- was my initial assumption wrong? So, is this practice actually a bad one, or is it secure? (I see no other reason so many sites would do this)

Comment: some services still send passwords as plain text in emails and stores them in a hash in db. Not good practice, but it's easy to do.

Comment: Why its such a bad idea would be a question for the security stack exchange site. How to do it is just as you describe, take the user input password as a variable, create a hash, save the hash then use the original variable in the email

Comment: *"First off, I realize this is an extremely bad practice"* - you're right, so why do it?

Comment: 1) Generate a password. 2) Hash it, store it in the database. 3) Send the plaintext password, which you still have in memory, because you just generated it, via email. – What's the issue?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Again, I **don't** want to do it. I simply wanted an explination of the process if it didn't work

Comment: @deceze- THANK YOU. You're the only person who actually read the question and gave an answer.

Comment: The question in my honest opinion, is too broad and what I would need to write, won't fit in a comment here. In doing so if I do write an answer, stand at getting downvoted for it. I could easily answer this with a bit of pseudo code, however and in a nutshell; just before you store the (safe) hash, the variable's that set for the password can be included in the email and then stored in db as a hash. `$pass=$_POST['pass']; echo $pass;` ... `$pass` is then saved to db with `password_hash()`; best I can do here ;-)

Comment: *"however, is it simply stored as plaintext in the server, or hashed after the email is sent?"* - We don't know how every service is used and what they really do. Some may store passwords as plain text, some may hash. Some may store plain text passwords inside a different location with a lock & key, some may do that and hash; it can be anything. If you're going to want to start a service of your own or is for a user signup site, then store passwords as a hash and not as plain text. There are too many scenarios for what you asked. I hope we've given you enough to get started. Moving on now ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could you copy/paste that comment as an answer? I'll accept it- that's the best answer yet, and looking at the reception this question got, I think it'll be the best answer I'll get

Comment: @Zack105 it has been done with a bit more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"@Fred-ii- Could you copy/paste that comment as an answer? I – Zack105"*

As requested:

*"however, is it simply stored as plaintext in the server, or hashed after the email is sent?"*

We don't know how every service is used and what they really do. Some may store passwords as plain text, some may hash. Some may store plain text passwords inside a different location with a lock & key, some may do that and hash; it can be anything.

If you're going to want to start a service of your own or is for a user signup site, then store passwords as a hash and not as plain text. There are too many scenarios for what you asked. I hope we've given you enough to get started.

Another thing if you don't know about this, are prepared statements and should be used if you are wanting to get user input and will help against a possible SQL injection.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php

---

A comment from [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze), pulled from a (now deleted) answer:

I quote:

*"Best practice is to let the user choose their own password, and to never store or send it in plaintext at any point. The password is a secret which must solely exist in the user's head (or secure password manager). The security of the user's account depends on the secrecy of the password. The more the password is being exposed in plaintext, the lower the security of the account." – deceze*

Answer (score 1):

**Don't.** It's that simple. Sites that do this do it out of laziness. They don't ever want support calls asking for passwords, or a technologically illiterate person has forced IT to do it. Passwords should *never* be sent over the wire in plaintext. People are stupid and reuse passwords, etc. If you're so worried that people have already forgotten their passwords, send them a link to your password reset page in that email.

Comment: Not really answering the question, but it's the only sensible answer.

Comment: I think you didn't really read the question..... I don't want to use this, I simply want to see if it works. Clearly, it doesn't, but I asked for a technological explanation, not someone telling me it doesn't work. I SPECIFICALLY said I didn't want that.

Comment: @Zack105 It does work, it should just never be done. You wrote "Is there anyway to send a password along with registration details, and still have the password stored as a hash?" with no mention of your intentions. That comes across as 'How do I accomplish this?' The how is irrelevant if the all the whys say not to.

Comment: I did mention my intentions- I specifically said I don't want to use this, and only want clarification on how secure this practice is.

Comment: Where? All I can see is your initial recognition that it's bad practice, then asking if that's an incorrect assumption.